# asp.net, userControl in editItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, user-controls

I'm using a user control in some edit item template (telerik radgrid).

But, my user control isn't well created and all its inner control are "null".

What can be wrong?

I have set a breakpoint in CreateChildControl() of my user control by I don't go in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you assign this user control as grid edit form? You can start from [this example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/dataediting/usercontroleditform/defaultcs.aspx) and do some comparison to see what differs and identify the issue culprit.

Comment: thanks I will look a it tomorrow. I was doing that way:
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn...>
<EditItemTemplate>
<uc:MyUserControl...>
</EditItemTemplate>
</telerik:GridTemplateColumn>